# Example for an algebraic field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}_p$ be the field with $p$ elements. Let $L:=Quot(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$ and $f\in L[x]$ be irreducible. Let $K:=L[x]/(f)$ and $w:=x+(f)\in K$. Consider $\mathbb{F}_p(w)\subset K$.

**Problem:** I now try to find an example, s.t. the field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(w)/\mathbb{F}_p$ is algebraic (respectively transcendental).

**Ideas:** I think I've got problems to deal with $\mathbb{F}_p(w)$, e.g. we could take $f$ to be $x-t$. This is irreducible, since we can take the prime element $t\in \mathbb{F}_p[t]$ and use Eisenstein's criterion and we have $t\nmid 1$, $t\mid t$ and $t^2\nmid t$. But I can't imagine how $\mathbb{F}_p(x+(x-t))$ looks like.

To proof that a field extension $\mathbb{F}_p(w)/\mathbb{F}_p$ is algebraic, it suffices to show $dim_{\mathbb{F}_p}(\mathbb{F}_p(w))=[\mathbb{F}_p(w):\mathbb{F}_p]<\infty$. Therefore I should calculate the basis of the $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space $\mathbb{F}_p(w)$. I guess $\mathbb{F}_p(x+(x-t))$ has dimension $2$.

Maybe there is also another strategy which is more useful.

Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb F_p(\omega)$ should be understood to be the smallest subfield of $L[x]/(f)=\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(f)$ that contains $\mathbb F_p$ and $\omega$, where $\omega$ is the residue class $x + (f)$. For this to make sense, note first that of course $\mathbb F_p$ is naturally embedded into $\mathbb F_p(t)[x] = \operatorname{Quot}(\mathbb F_p[t])[x]$, by mapping an element of $\mathbb F_p$ to its corresponding constant polynomial. Taking the factor ring $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(f)$, since $f$ is non-constant, this embedding survives. Thus we may think of $\mathbb F_p$ as a subfield of $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(f)$.
(N.b.: Actually this also follows simply because $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(f)$ is a field of characteristic $p$, and thus $\mathbb F_p$ is its prime field.)

To figure out what $\mathbb F_p(\omega)$ is, we need to find the smallest subfield of $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(f)$ which, in addition to $\mathbb F_p$, also contains the element $\omega$. In your example with $f=x-t$ we have an isomorphism $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(f)\cong \mathbb F_p(t)$ with $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i + (f)\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^n a_i t^i$. Under this isomorphism $\omega = x + (f)$ maps to $t$. Thus $\mathbb F_p(\omega) \cong \mathbb F_p(t)$, which is in fact transcendental.

To get an algebraic extension, try choosing your polynomial $f$ in such a way, that in fact $f \in \mathbb F_p[x]$.